# How do I constrain T to be an unsigned integral?

Tags: c#, type-constraints

I have been trying the following

```
interface IUIntegral : IEquatable<Byte>, IEquatable<UInt16>, IEquatable<UInt32>, IEquatable<UInt64> { }
class Counter<T> where T : IUIntegral {
    T _value;
}
```

With this calling code

```
Counter<UInt32> foo = null;
```

But I get this compiler error

```
Error   1   The type 'uint' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Test.Counter<T>'. There is no boxing conversion from 'uint' to 'Test.IUIntegral'.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tldr;** This approach will not work.

C# uses a [nominative type system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_type_system) (types are determined by names) and *not* a [structural type system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) (types determined by data/operations).

`unit32` and `IUIntegral` are not related: *even if they share the same structure*.

(They don't anyway, `uint32` does not conform to `IEquatable<byte>`.)

If a type needs to be Equatable with itself this can be done by referring to the type in a type restriction:

```
class Counter<T> where T : IEquatable<T> {
    T _value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome explanation. Is there any way to constrain types in C#? I have been reading about `CodeContracts` but can't seem to find any documentation on static assertions. I was hoping they might work.

Comment: @NickStrupat At the type-level you're pretty much restricted to `T : uint32`, `T : IEquatable<unit32>`, `T : IEquatable<T>` (which might work for you here) or something very much broader. I have not played with code-contracts, so I don't know how they work.